# Scala Dotty Union Type?

Tags: scala, dotty

Using the sbt dotty plugin:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.felixmulder" % "sbt-dotty" % "0.1.9")
```

And running `sbt console`, I try out the new union type feature:

```
Starting dotty interpreter...
Welcome to Scala.next (pre-alpha, git-hash: 606e36b)  (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_112).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
scala> case class A(val x: Int, y: Double) 
defined class A
scala> case class B(val x: Int, y: String) 
defined class B
scala> def getX(o: A | B): Int = o.x 
-- [E008] Member Not Found Error: <console> ------------------------------------
8 |def getX(o: A | B): Int = o.x
  |                          ^^^
  |                          value `x` is not a member of (A | B)(o)
```

Why doesn't this work? Am I using union types wrong? Is this just not working yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's supposed to actually work. It *does* work if `A` and `B` extend a common interface that asserts they each have an `x: Int`:

```
trait C { def x: Int }

case class A(x: Int, y: Double) extends C

case class B(x: Int, y: String) extends C

def getX(o: A | B): Int = o.x

scala> getX(A(1, 2)) 
val res0: Int = 1
```

Without it, the compiler would need to reflectively look at `A` and `B` to determine if they had the same `x` defined, which doesn't seem in line with the goal of simplifying Scala's type system.

Of course, the supporting documentation is pretty much non-existent with no complete specification at this point. I think perhaps [this slide](https://d-d.me/talks/scalaworld2015/#/11) is a source of confusion, as it isn't compilable code.

Comment: That DarkDimius slide was the source of my confusion. Thank you.

Comment: If A and B must common interface, then we are using inheritance. How is union type better than this or help in this case?

Comment: @thlim Because the union type is used as proof that `o` is an `A` or `B`. Union types on their own say nothing about how `A` and `B` are related, because they don't have to be.